# What is difference between bar-chart and bar-chart-o in fontawsome

Tags: css, font-awesome

in website http://fontawesome.io/icons/ there is bar-chart and bar-chart-o (alias) icons
but when when click to see description its go to same page [url](http://fontawesome.io/icon/bar-chart/) so what is difference.

```
<i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i> //same html
```

thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer Why it need to have alias

Comment: Perhaps for backward compatibility, but i'm not sure. You'd see that there are more aliases there - it's not the only one

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, it is simply an alias! See the following example using both CSS classes:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```